# Ruby on rails - MS SQL In Clause limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner in ruby. I recently migrated the DB from postgres to Azure SQL. Most of the things are working fine, but one particular functionality started failing. This is related to SQL statement where "IN" clause contains around 65000 values, comma separated. Below is the code snippet that I think is failing. Is it possible to write the SQL query and not rely on what ruby calls internally. To be honest, I dont even know what line is actually hitting the DB. The table name is drugs and the column used in where clause is "id":

```
def all
  priced_drugs = apply_prices_and_info(drugs)
  all = AllMetadataLookup.lookup_as_map(ndcs(drugs), start_date, end_date)
  all.merge! drugs: priced_drugs
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: all }
  end
end
```

The error that I can see in logs is :
'ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: DBPROCESS is dead or not enabled: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [drugs].* FROM [drugs] WHERE [drugs].[id] IN (29129, 29130, 29131,[very very long statement])

Comment: You may achieve this using subquery. Could you please shared method definition for `apply_prices_and_info` & `lookup_as_map`?

Comment: def apply_prices_and_info(data)
      ndcs = ndcs(data)
      apply_prices(data, ndcs)
      apply_info(data, ndcs) if include_drug_info
      data
    end